# My react app is adding a new item instead of updating and replacing the item, how can I fix it to replace the item instead of adding another new item

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-redux

My react app is adding a new item instead of updating and replacing the item. Instead of replacing the item it adds another new item underneath it.

The code:

```
import Button from "./Button"
import Input from "./Input"

import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { server_calls } from '../api/server'
import { useDispatch, useStore } from 'react-redux';
import { chooseISBN, chooseAuthor, chooseTitle, chooseLength, chooseCover } from "../redux/slices/RootSlice";

interface ContactFormProps {
  id?: string[]
}

const ContactForm = (props:ContactFormProps) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({})
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const store = useStore();

  const onSubmit = (data: any, event: any) => {
    console.log(`ID: ${typeof props.id}`);
    console.log(props.id)
    console.log(data)
    if (props.id && props.id.length > 0 ) {
      server_calls.update(props.id[0], data)
      console.log(`Updated: ${ data.name } ${ props.id }`)
      setTimeout(() => {window.location.reload()}, 1000);
      event.target.reset()
    } else {
      dispatch(chooseISBN(data.isbn_number));
      dispatch(chooseAuthor(data.author_name));
      dispatch(chooseTitle(data.book_title));
      dispatch(chooseLength(data.book_length));
      dispatch(chooseCover(data.hardcover_or_paperback)); 

      server_calls.create(store.getState())
      setTimeout( () => {window.location.reload()}, 1000);

    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="isbn_number">ISBN</label>
          <Input {...register('isbn_number')} name='isbn_number' placeholder="ISBN"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="author_name">Author</label>
          <Input {...register('author_name')} name='author_name' placeholder="Author"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="book_title">Title</label>
          <Input {...register('book_title')} name='book_title' placeholder="Title"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="book_length">Length</label>
          <Input {...register('book_length')} name='book_length' placeholder="Length"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="hardcover_or_paperback">Cover</label>
          <Input {...register('hardcover_or_paperback')} name='hardcover_or_paperback' placeholder="Cover"/>
        </div>
        <div className="flex p-1">
          <Button
            className="flex justify-start m-3 bg-slate-300 p-2 rounded hover:bg-slate-800 text-white"
            >
              Submit
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  )
}

export default ContactForm
```

I have tried updating the ContactFormProps interface to specify that id is a string instead of an array of strings.

But still does the same thing, it will add another new item but not update and replace the selected item to be updated.

Comment: Hi Miguel, please provide code and not screenshots of code